# LevelDB Java API

Tags: leveldb

I am creating a project using java library from https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni but it gives me this error

UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni32-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni in java.library.path

I just added leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar imn my project. I have looked up this problem and I found out I needed dlls, where can i find these?

Answer (score 0):

y can try to add leveldbjni-win32-1.8.jar in you project besides  leveldbjni-1.8.jar

reference: https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni